# React-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'migrationrepository.retrievemigrationversions().pipe

Tags: react-native

I try to install my non-empty React-Native app on my phone without success. I am on ubuntu 22, when I run my application with "npx react-native run-android" it starts to install on my phone then it generates the following error: [screen of my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLPPH.png)